# convert list of values .txt to vector and plot

Tags: python

I have two txt files. The datas in the first one are :

```
0
0.1
0.5
0.3
```

and in the second one are:

```
20
32
35
39
```

So what I wanna do is:
1º read both text files 2º save the differents values in a vector. 3º plot

In this moment I have done the following code:

```
fichero = open('signal1t.txt','r')

listx = []

for linea in fichero:

        listx.append(linea.strip() )

fichero = open('signal2.txt','r')

listy = []

for linea in fichero:

        listay.append(linea.strip() )
```

But the problem is that it doesn't run very well. In fact it doesn't save numbers ...
Is there anybody that can help me?

Comment: Look up `matplotlib`

Comment: "In fact it doesn't save numbers". What makes you think that? Your program doesn't have any `print` statements or anything, so how can you tell?

Comment: What do you mean by "3º plot"?

Answer (score 1):

a simpler solution is tu use numpy :

```
import numpy as np
listx=np.loadtxt('signal1t.txt')
listy=np.loadtxt('signal2t.txt')
```

Then you just have to plot using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(listx,listy)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to typecast the read string to float:

```
listx.append(float(linea.strip()))
```

Comment: `.strip()` isn't needed here since `float()` (and `int()`) happily cope with leading & trailing whitespace.

Comment: ok - thanks for the information. Though it doesn't hurt so I generally `strip()` of trailings before proceeding with whatever data processing.

Comment: It doesn't hurt, but it is a little slower, since you're calling an extra method for every data item. Just let `float()` do the work for you, so everything's happening at C speed.

Answer (score 0):

What you wish to do is very simple with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

listx = np.genfromtxt('signal1.txt')
listy = np.genfromtxt('signal2.txt')

plt.plot(listx, listy, 'x')
plt.show()
```